# How to use SAML when one user want to impersonate another user

Tags: authentication, impersonation, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have following scenario:

UserA has access to ApplicationA.

UserB has access to ApplicationB.
Both ApplicationA and ApplicationB uses ApplicationI as identity provider (custom  implementation).

While logged-in in ApplicationA, UserA wants to single sign on to ApplicationB as UserB(Assume UserB has given such permission to UserA).

ApplicationB should know that UserA is logged-in as UserB.

How can I use SAML 2.0 in this case? So far whatever examples I got on web about SAML is for a single user trying Single sign on as himself on multipl sites, but not for a user impersonating another user on another site.
Specifically, I am trying to understand how I can use SAML Web SSO profile with HttpBinding in this case.

Comment: This sounds like a bad solution. Why would you wan UserA to use UserBs account? In essence UserA is UserA and should only be signed in as such. If you explain the reason for this maybe we can come up with a better solution

Comment: Single sign on is when a user with a unique set of credentials is accessing multiple services without entering his credentials for each of them. can you please explain the reason for such a requirement?

Comment: This about a call center rep. They may need special access to a customer's account to see what they are reporting. Access to the Application is controlled via a SAML Response. SAML is just one way in which this info can be confidently transferred between application that may have different security domains.

Answer (score 1):

Impersonation is not an unheard of requirement. UserA and UserB identity info can both be passed within a SAML Response, but it's potentially up to AppA and AppB to have a common AuthZ model so that you don't get some malicious activity.

So, for example, AppA would authenticate UserA. When UserA wants to SSO to AppB and impersonate UserB, a Response would be generated for UserA by AppA with UserB's identity passed within an Attribute where "ImpersonateUser=UserB". UserA would be the SUBJECT of the Response. When AppB (acting as the SP) validates the Response, it would need to ensure UserA is allowed to impersonate UserB via an internal authorization mapping. Or, AppB could simple trust that AppA has already validated that UserA can impersonate UserB and create the session appropriately. However, this depends on the trust relationship between AppA and AppB.

HTH,
Ian

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks. this solves the problem of how to construct the SAML response. Could you also please specify how in the SAML Request that UserA wants to impersonate UserB? in SAMLRequest I can only specify information which identifies only one Subject or Principal? How should I speify that this request is for impersonation?

Comment: I would suggest that the AuthnRequst is not the place for this info. Probably better to make a Attribute Query back to the IDP to get this type of info. Alternatively, you would provision this info ahead of time (out of band) and not need to call back to the IDP.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question in your reply to Ian, one way to inform the IDP using AuthnRequest that you want to impersonate another user is to use Extensions element of the AuthnRequest.